# Is there a way to force c# code to prompt for pin code using Gemalto smart card?

Tags: c#, prompt, smartcard, gemalto

I'm looking for a way to force c# code to enable PIN prompt to the user with Gemalto smart card, I have tried :

```
PIN pin = new PIN("0000", 3);
pin.Verify("0000");
```

I created The PIN Object only to use verify method

Comment: Show what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I tried the class PIN and verify method of Gemalto API : public void verify , but nothing occurs , thanks

Comment: Add the code to your question.

Comment: I added the code to my question, thanks